# Using React defaultProps to correctly set initial state of prop

Tags: reactjs

My question is about Focus question from:
https://www.testdome.com/d/react-js-interview-questions/304

I got this far:

```
class Input extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    let {forwardedRef, ...otherProps} = this.props; 
    return <input {...otherProps} ref={forwardedRef} />;
  }
}

const TextInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <Input {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
});

class FocusableInput extends React.Component {

  ref = React.createRef()

  render() {
    return <TextInput ref={this.ref} />;
  }

  // When the focused prop is changed from false to true, 
  // and the input is not focused, it should receive focus.
  // If focused prop is true, the input should receive the focus.
  // Implement your solution below:
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.focused !== this.props.focused && !!this.props.focused)
    {
      if (this.ref.current !== document.activeElement)
      {
        this.ref.current.focus();
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {}
}

FocusableInput.defaultProps = {
  focused: true
};

const App = (props) => <FocusableInput focused={props.focused} />;

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I got:

```
The focused property has an initial state of true: Wrong answer 
Changing the focused prop from false to true focuses the input: Correct answer
```

So I got second test correct but not the first, the one asking for props.focused having the initial state of true.

Looking at my code, it seems I already set it to true?

Comment: I still want to solve it. Can someone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't sign under it, but this is what that exercise expects. If `focused` prop is `true`, you have to focus the input inside `componentDidMount`. Also if the `focused` prop changes - focus has to be changed as well.

```
class FocusableInput extends React.Component {
  ref;

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.focused !== this.props.focused) {
      this.ref.focus();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.focused) {
      this.ref.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <TextInput ref={(ref) => this.ref = ref} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: this.ref.focus() needs to be this.ref.current.focus() but yeh, now both tests passed :D

Comment: @logan I prefer to use callback refs:)